# Cursor Location On Zoom for IE, PanZoom

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svgpanzoom

I am using the Panzoom.js plugin to pan and zoom an element. There is a mask applied to the cursor, the cursor reveals a portion of the underlying image wherever it hovers over the image(imagine a black and white image on top of a colored image, the cursor would reveal a portion of the colored image where ever the cursor hovers over the image). When i zoom in on the image in Chrome and Safari(using Panzoom), the mouse coordinates are given properly and thus the mask lines up properly with the cursor. However, in Firefox and IE while zooming in the cursor coordinates are not correct and thus the hover mask doesn't align properly with the cursor. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for looking into this. Below is the code.

```
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

function cursorPoint(evt) {
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;
    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function getCanvasCoords(x, y) {
    var matrix = $panzoom.panzoom("getMatrix");

    var calc_x = x * (1 / matrix[0]);
    var calc_y = y * (1 / matrix[3]);

    return {
        x: calc_x,
        y: calc_y
    };
}

$("#parentID").mousemove(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var loc = cursorPoint(event);

    var img = document.getElementById("parentID");
    var imgPos = img.getBoundingClientRect();

    var x = loc.x - imgPos.left;
    var y = loc.y - imgPos.top;
    var coords = getCanvasCoords(x, y);

    primaryCircle.setAttribute("cy", (coords.y) + "px");
    primaryCircle.setAttribute("cx", (coords.x) + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round

```
function getCanvasCoords(x, y) {
    var matrix = $panzoom.panzoom("getMatrix");

    var calc_x = x * Math.round((1 / matrix[0]));
    var calc_y = y * Math.round(1 / matrix[3]); 

    return {
        x: calc_x,
        y: calc_y
    };
}
```